# SharePoint 2010 Choice Box Value Suppression?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

In SharePoint 2010 I created a form for my users with two choice boxes that have specific options.  The users asked me to suppress some of those values so they can never be used again, but they don't want to lose those values on historical records.  Is there a way to suppress/hide values in a choice box?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the choice field options and it won't change the existing records.  The old records will only change if you go back and save over them again.

You would have to worry if you were using a lookup field.  Then if you change the values they are represented in older items immediately.